# How to make 3d interactive graphics in Julia?

Tags: plotly, julia

I found a web page with a similar tutorial. But when I copy the code to run, it gives an error. Hope you all can help me.
[enter link description here](https://plotly.com/julia/3d-surface-plots/)

```
using PlotlyJS, CSV, HTTP, DataFrames
# Read data from a csv
df = CSV.File(
    HTTP.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv").body
) |> DataFrame
z_data = Matrix{Float64}(df)
layout = Layout(
    title="Mt Bruno Elevation",
    autosize=false,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    margin=attr(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90)
)
plot(surface(z=z_data), layout)
```

The error he gave me is as follows.

```
ERROR: IOError(Base.IOError("getaddrinfo: no such file or directory (ENOENT)", -4058) during request(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv))
```

Comment: This seems like a network issue. Do you have a firewall or something that may be blocking access to that `githubusercontent` page? Can you try visiting this url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv from your browser and see if it loads?

Comment: Ok,thanks.problem almost solved.